# XNA How to create bones

Tags: xna

I loaded custom model from binary file, but now I dont know how use my bone data. Is there any way to use it for ModelBone or something like this? I have CustomBone[]:

```
class CustomBone 
{
    int parentIndex;
    Vector3 positionAbs;
    Quaternion rotationAbs;
    Vector3 positionRel;
    Quaternion rotationRel;
}
```

Or how to fill ModelBoneCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you cannot create or modify a `Model` at runtime ([details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/08/03/content-pipeline-optional.aspx)). If fact, if you need to, you are supposed to [implement your own](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/09/19/note-to-self-model-hammer.aspx). `Model` is just the bare-minimum of functionality to get you started.

However you *can* create a `Model` at build-time, via the content pipeline.

Or, more specifically, you can create a custom content importer that outputs `NodeContent`. In turn this can be passed, through the content pipeline, to `ModelProcessor` (or your own class derived from it) which will output `ModelContent`. You can't usefully modify `ModelContent` either. The `ModelContent` will be serialized, and then loaded as a `Model` at runtime.

The `NodeContent` to output is a tree structure that represents your model. It will actually be made up of `MeshContent` and `BoneContent` nodes (these are classes derived from `NodeContent`).

To be honest, the exact structure of that tree is a bit tricky to track down (the documentation is a very lacking). [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26647/288) is a question and answer that should set you on the right track. You might have also luck by using the built-in `FbxImporter` with a known model, and inspecting its output with the [XNA Content Pipeline Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/11/01/xna-content-pipeline-debugging-4-0.aspx) (a tool that will generally come in handy while implementing your own importer).

---

The bone data is stored as a `Matrix` in `BoneContent.Transform`. To create this matrix, I believe you need to do something like this:

```
boneContent.Transform = Matrix.Transform(
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(customBone.positionRel),
        customBone.rotationRel);
```

If you want to keep your bone data as a `Quaternion` at runtime, you will have to implement your own alternative to `Model`.